# date filter on input element with data-ng-model

Tags: angularjs

Formatting date in input element with `ng-model` seems to be a problem. I have date in string format. It is working fine with `value` attribute but does not work with `ng-model`. Am I missing something. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srnug/137/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = "09-29-2015";
}

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="date | date:'yyyy'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `angular-datetime` directive

```
<input type="text" datetime="yyyy" ng-model="date">
```

https://github.com/eight04/angular-datetime

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
   placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2013-01-01" max="2013-12-31" required />
```

or try this

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
{{date | date:'yyyy'}}<br/> 
</div>

function Ctrl($scope)
 {
    $scope.date = new Date();
  }
```

See this [Angular jS date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D)

Update fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/kGGCZ/973/)

It was working for me

Comment: I want to display year from date. How can I gt this done

Comment: can you please explain me how you want to display

Comment: @Carlos try this date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z and see this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: you want only year to be displayed

Comment: Filter is working fine with expressions but they are not working with input element ng-model. That is my question

Comment: please let me know  is this what you want

Comment: did you checked fiddle is this what you want

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like your date is a string, try making it a date.
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
    }